# My custom editor doesn't find the fields I'm looking for

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor, unity3d-editor

```
void OnEnable()
{
    iteminfo = (ItemInfo)target;
    itemName = serializedObject.FindProperty(iteminfo.Name);
}

public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    serializedObject.Update();
    **EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(itemName);**
    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
}
```

It says there is a null reference and i cant find where to change it.

Here are the other Scripts

```
   public class ItemInfo : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Item Item_Info;
        public enum ItemType { Weapon, Armor, Potion, Other };
        public ItemType itemtype;

        public int damage;

        public int Defense;

        public int heal_value;
    
        private Inventory playerinventory;
    }
```

and then heres the item script is

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name, Description;
    public bool stackable;
    public int Value, weight;
    public string ModelPath;
}
```

Im trying to grab the "Name" in

```
public class Item
```

Comment: On which line? Are you sure `target` is valid?

Comment: @RetiredNinja i think it is on the line where is says "EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(itemName)" and i think that target isnt the problem.

Comment: Could you show us your `ItemInfo` implementation?

Comment: `ItemInfo` doesn't have any field or property called `Name` ....

Comment: @derHugo sorry i forgot to add the other 2 scripts but here you go

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with your custom editor? For now it would be `itemName  = serializedObject.FindProperty("Item").FindPropertyRelative("Name");` .. though still not sure if/how this really helps you

Comment: @derHugo all im trying to do is if i pick Armour as the enum it would only show defense and not damage or healValue

Comment: .. wait so you want to go by the `itemtype` .. then what do you need the item name for?

Comment: because right now its not displaying anything in the inspector (for the script) so i just thought the best idea was to put the name threw there and then make "If" statements for the different enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want to do:

First of all if not anyway the case make the `Item` class `[Serializable]`.

Then have e.g. this editor

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(ItemInfo))]
public class ItemInfoEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty item;
    private SerializedProperty itemType;
    private SerializedProperty damage;
    private SerializedProperty defense;
    private SerializedProperty heal;

    private ItemInfo itemInfo;
    
    void OnEnable()
    {
        itemInfo = (ItemInfo)target;
        
        // Link up the properties via the according field names
        item = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(ItemInfo.Item_Info));
        itemType = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(ItemInfo.itemtype));
        damage = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(ItemInfo.damage));
        defense = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(ItemInfo.Defense));
        heal = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(ItemInfo.heal_value));
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        // just draw the default script field
        DrawScriptField();
        
        serializedObject.Update();
        
        // draw the Item field itself
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(item, true);
        // draw the item type dropdown
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(itemType);
        
        // according to the selected value draw the according field(s)
        switch ((ItemInfo.ItemType)itemType.intValue)
        {
            case ItemInfo.ItemType.Weapon:
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(damage);
                break;
            
            case ItemInfo.ItemType.Armor:
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(defense);
                break;
            
            case ItemInfo.ItemType.Potion:
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(heal);
                break;

            case ItemInfo.ItemType.Other:
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(damage);
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(heal);
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(defense);
                break;
        }
        
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    private void DrawScriptField()
    {
        EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
        EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Script", MonoScript.FromMonoBehaviour(itemInfo), typeof(ItemInfo), false);
        EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
        
        EditorGUILayout.Space();
    }
}
```

[image]